# unit test in ruby not printing results to console

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to set up a testing environment in ruby using rake.  It seems like the code I have gets reached by rake but it doesn't return any test results.  I'm hoping I'm missing something simple and you could lend me a hand.

rakefile

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
      t.libs = ["lib"]
      t.warning = true
      t.verbose = true
      t.test_files = ['test/numbersTest_test.rb']
end

task default:[:test]
```

numbersTest_test.rb

```
require "test/unit"

class TestMyApplication < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def dummyCase
        assert(false, "dummy case failed")
    end
end
```

Result when I run "rake"

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Classes\assign1\PerfectNumbersRuby
λ rake
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -w -I"lib" -I"C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/numbersTest_test.rb"
test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no testcases in your code. Testcases are methods whose name starts with `test_`.

Comment: You are correct, I found out by accident because I'm bad at documentation.  Thank you for your time, you've earned your points.